# When reading BERTLV, when do you stop?

Tags: asn.1, tlv, ber

I have the following BERTLV:
`61394F0BA00000030800001001234579074F05A000012345500E49442D4F6E65205049562042494F5F50107777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D7F66080202800002028000`

I'm trying to parse this in a recursive way, so I am treating the first part as a TLV.

Tag: `0x61`, Len: `0x39`, Value: `4F0BA00000030800001001234579074F05A000012345500E49442D4F6E65205049562042494F5F50107777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D`

Then I break it down further, and get

Tag: `0x4F`, Len: `0x0B`, Value:
`A000000308000010012345`

Now, how do I stop? At this point, I know this value is the last leg of this TLV and is not another nested TLV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok after much digging, I found out what the simple `TAG` is actually more than just a number, the `TAG` itself actually encoded a brunch of information in there. I order to find out whether the `TLV` contains nested `TLV` so that my code would know when to continue processing and when to stop, I had to decode the `TAG`.

So the `TAG` contains 8 bits, and each one of them have special meaning:

[image: TLV TAG and their bits meaning]

The bit that I needed was `B5` in order to determine whether the current `TLV` is `Constructed` or not... when is `Constructed` it means that current `TLV` consists of multiple `TLV`, so for my code, I am using this information to recursively dig in the nested `TLV`.

When the `TLV` is **not** `Constructed` that is my stopping case to bubble back up.

Here is my recursive function output by parsing the data and checking the bit `B5` in `TAG`:

```
11:20:38.428 Parsing: 61394F0BA00000030800001000010079074F05A000000308500E49442D4F6E65205049562042494F5F50107777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D7F66080202800002028000
11:20:38.436 Constructed Data Object
11:20:38.437 Parsing: 4F0BA00000030800001000010079074F05A000000308500E49442D4F6E65205049562042494F5F50107777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D
11:20:38.437 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.437 tag: 79, len: 11, value: A000000308000010000100
11:20:38.437 Constructed Data Object
11:20:38.437 Parsing: 4F05A000000308
11:20:38.437 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.437 tag: 79, len: 5, value: A000000308
11:20:38.437 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.437 tag: 80, len: 14, value: 49442D4F6E65205049562042494F
11:20:38.437 MultiByte tag
11:20:38.437 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.437 tag: 24400, len: 16, value: 7777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D
11:20:38.438 MultiByte tag
11:20:38.438 Constructed Data Object
11:20:38.438 Parsing: 0202800002028000
11:20:38.438 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.438 tag: 2, len: 2, value: 8000
11:20:38.438 Primitive Data Object
11:20:38.438 tag: 2, len: 2, value: 8000
```

Comment: Where is the table from?

Comment: @Ayxan I forgot the exact location, but it was from one of those ISO standards PDF files. Either from www.itu.int or www.etsi.org

Comment: I did find it. It's on EMV Book 3 page 156

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Now, how do I stop?

**A:** The TAG Length (0x0B) represented in HEX and show the amount of Bytes in the Value. Every Byte represented in your example as 2 (two) Hex characters. So the 0x0B which is 11 in decimal show you 11*2 = 22 characters in Value to use.

Here is parsing example of your BER-TLV buffer parsed by https://iso8583.info/lib/EMV/TLVs tool:

```
---
# Cheef's parser.
# Copyright (C) 2008-2017 Alexander Shevelev. https://iso8583.info/
# lib   : "/lib/EMV/" - Integrated Circuit Card Specifications for Payment Systems
# tool  : "TLVs"
# stat  : 40 nodes, 4 lookup tables, 25.00% passed (1/4)

TLVs:#"61394F0BA00000030800001001234579074F05A000012345500E49442D4F..8000" # EMV, Tag + Length + Value (TLV) series
- x61:#"61394F0BA00000030800001001234579074F05A000012345500E49442D4F..6F6D" # ISO 7816, Template, Application
  - tag: "61"
  - len: "39" #  // 57
  - val:#"4F0BA00000030800001001234579074F05A000012345500E49442D4F6E65..6F6D" # Template, Application.
    - x4F:#"4F0BA000000308000010012345" # ISO 7816, Application Identifier (AID), Card
      - tag: "4F"
      - len: "0B" #  // 11
      - val:#"A000000308000010012345" # AID, Card.
        - RID: "A000000308" # Registered Application Provider Identifier (RID) // National Institute of Standards and Technology
        - PIX: "000010012345" # Proprietary Application Identifier Extension (PIX)
    - x79:#"79074F05A000012345" # ISO 7816, Coexistent Tag Allocation Authority
      - tag: "79"
      - len: "07" #  // 7
      - val:#"4F05A000012345"
        - x4F:#"4F05A000012345" # ISO 7816, Application Identifier (AID), Card
          - tag: "4F"
          - len: "05" #  // 5
          - val:#"A000012345" # AID, Card.
            - RID: "A000012345" # Registered Application Provider Identifier (RID)
    - x50:#"500E49442D4F6E65205049562042494F" # ISO 7816, Application Label
      - tag: "50"
      - len: "0E" #  // 14
      - val: "49442D4F6E65205049562042494F" # Application Label. // ID-One PIV BIO
    - x5F50:#"5F50107777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D" # ISO 7816, Uniform resource locator (URL)
      - tag: "5F50"
      - len: "10" #  // 16
      - val: "7777772E6F626572746875722E636F6D" # URL. // www.oberthur.com
- x7F66:#"7F66080202800002028000"
  - tag: "7F66"
  - len: "08" #  // 8
  - val:#"0202800002028000"
    - x02:#"02028000"
      - tag: "02"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
      - val: "8000"
    - x02:#"02028000"
      - tag: "02"
      - len: "02" #  // 2
      - val: "8000"
```

Comment: I know the length (L) is the size of how many bytes to read in the TLV, but if you look at my BERTLV. The first TLV actually contains 2 TLV inside, and then the first TLV also contains 2 TLV again. When do you know when is nested and when is not is more of my question. I know plenty of parser on the web, but that's not what I'm trying to figure out when I mean "stop" hehe...

Comment: BTW, thank you for the site `https://iso8583.info`, there is some info I can get there, but where else can I find all the supported tags, for instance, `0x7F66` is showing as `Unknown Tag`

Comment: Glad that you found the BER-TLV (ASN.1 BER) and definition of constructed Tag. Tag 0x7F66 value is not described in the example because it is not a part of Contact EMV specification used for this data breakdown. It is only the sample of parsing nested tags. Simple search for "Tag 7F66" can point you to descriptions in ISO 24727-2 and deeper into ISO 7816-15 specifications.

Comment: Why wouldn't the first tag be `0x01` instead of `0x61`? According to ISO/IEC 7816-4, Section 5.2.2.1 only the least significant 5 bits encode the tag number (when those 5 bits aren't all set to 1).

Comment: Adam, Tag IDs are reserved by different specifications. In the example Template Tag 0x61 used by ISO 7816. Tags from 0x01 to 0x31 reserved to ASN.1 BER-TLV (ISO 8825-1) Generic types. Here is the list of tags (https://iso8583.info/lib/ISO/8825/1/BER/TLVs)